# При выборе категории отображается подкатегория. Как это сделать?

Tags: php, javascript

В общем при добавлении товара в магазин пользователь выбирает раздел.

```
echo 'Раздел: <select name="cat">';
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `shop_cat` ORDER BY `realid`;');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select><br/>';
```

При выборе допустим первого раздела нужно сделать так чтобы появлялся ниже подраздел с категориями первого раздела. Если второй - то соответственно подраздел с категориями второго раздела.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузите все категории (я думаю их не так уж много и много времени не займет), а затем примените к списку плагин jQuery.treeview();

**UPD**

[jquery.treeview()](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/)

Comment: Что за плагин?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script> 
    function processStateChange(){
      if (request.readyState == 4){
        contentDiv = document.getElementById(dest);
        if (request.status == 200)
                        {
                            response = request.responseText;
                            contentDiv.innerHTML = response;
                        } 
        else 
                {
                    contentDiv.innerHTML = "Error: Status "+request.status;

                }
      }
    }

 // Это функция получет содермжимое от файла URL и разместить на элемент по АйДи destination  
    function loadHTML(URL, destination){
      dest = destination;
      URL=URL+'&cache='+(new Date().getTime());

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = processStateChange;
        request.open("GET", URL, true);
        request.send(null);
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if (request) {
    request.onreadystatechange = processStateChange;
    request.open("GET", URL, true);
    request.send();
        }
      }
    }

<?    
    echo 'Раздел: <select name="cat" onchange="loadHTML(\'podrazdel.php?razdel\' + this.selectedIndex, \'razdelDiv\') ">';
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `shop_cat` ORDER BY `realid`;');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select><br/>';
?>
     <div id='razdelDiv'></div>

///////////////
///  Теперь podrazdel.php
<?
echo 'ПодРаздел: <select name="sub_cat" >';
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `shop_sub_cat` where cat_id='.$HTTP_GET_VARS["razdel"] .'  ORDER BY `realid`;');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select><br/>';
?>
```

Comment: Я конечно сделал по-другому. И по-проще. Ну и так попробую.

Comment: Не работает. Подкатегории не выводятся.

Comment: а таблица подкатегорий как называется. Я условно `shop_sub_cat` написал...

Comment: Я заменил на свою. Все равно не работает.

Comment: а на файле podrazdel.php подключение к базе есть?

Comment: Конечно есть.


<?
require '../system/core.php';
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `shop_podcat` WHERE `id_cat`='.$HTTP_GET_VARS["razdel"] .' ORDER BY `realid`;');
echo 'Подраздел: <select name="podcat">
<option value="null">- Выберите подраздел -</option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select><br/>';
?>